# JWT signature is invalid when using private key

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am trying to create a web token as part of my test app to authenticate with [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5). I have created the cert etc with the following commands:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out csr.pem

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out server.crt
```

Here is my fairly simple code right now:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const claims = { 
    "iss":"3MVG9p1Q1BCe9GmBj3_niA0vfZ6uaNFOHznL4ScHnVB7_T5MnF.qtqtlCu2b0BW8MZOu4BY7Yn3Aur", 
    "aud": "https://login.salesforce.com", 
}

async function test() {
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8');

  const token = await jwt.sign(claims, privateKey, {algorithm: 'RS256'});
  console.log(token);

}
test();
```

When I drop that token into jwt.io I get the following Invalid Signature error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what the text in the Verify Signature means. Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Updated to enter public/private keys with the same result:
[image]

Comment: jwt.io needs the public key to verify the token. Without knowing the key, it's impossible to verify the token. Copy the contents of your public key file into the upper field under 'Verify signature'

Answer (score 0):

jwt.io tries to download the public key from the URL found in your issuer claim, but as the issuer is not a URL, it can't validate the signature of the token.

As the commenter said, you need to copy the public key manually into jwt.io.

Comment: I've updated to enter the details mentioned and its the same result. Updated screenshot attached